# ckfinder is not able to access the remote server files

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, nginx, ftp, ckfinder

I'm using CKFinder in my web app (based Laravel), in order to navigate and upload files to an nginx storage server.
I manage to do so when developing on localhost, so the connectivity between the client app and the storage server was using FTP.
After deploying the app into appEngine server, I'm getting the error: "It was not possible to complete the request due to file system permission restrictions".
Nothing have changed in the depolyed applocation, the code is exactly the same as in the localhost. except for the fact that the appEngine runs the app over https instead of http.
what might be the problem for this issus?

here are some of my configurations for ckfinder:

config.php:

```
$config['backends'][] = array(
 'name'         => 'my_conntection',
 'adapter'      => 'ftp',
 'host'         => 'hostnname',
 'username'     => 'username',
 'password'     => 'password',
 'root'         => '/upload',
 'chmodFiles'   => 0644,
 'chmodFolders' => 0755,
 'baseUrl'      => 'https://hostname/upload',
 'passive'      => 'false',
);
```

What should I also do? Am I missing something?

Is there any alternatives for this annoying ckfinder?

Comment: How did you deploy? Check your file permissions on the new server instance... your destination folders must be writable...

Comment: @Serge I believe the destination folders are writable, because I'm able to connect to it and upload files when using localhost (it's the same storage server for both the local and production).

Comment: What FTP server are you using? Culd you please enable debug mode (https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/debugging.html#debugging_debugging) and check details of this error in error log?

Comment: @zaak the debug mode is giving me a hard time. this is what I'm getting so far:
Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: ftp_mkdir(): Can't create directory: File exists in /app/public/scripts/MyCity/FilesManager/templateEditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Ftp.php